# How to get last five items from database using id's

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a personal project where I made a small CMS.
Currently I extract the id's that each newly added message will get with a foreachloop like this:

```
    <li><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $article['article_content']; ?></a> - <small><?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp']); ?></small></li>
            <?php } ?>
```

The downside is that I send the ID to a new page using this line:

```
    <li><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
```

But I would like to print the 5 lastest that have been added messages to the database. currently my table contains an A_I article_id, article_content, article_timestamp and article_title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Don't know what I was thinking, but apperently I was thinking way to hard ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT article_id,article_title,article_content,article_timestamp
  FROM articles ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: A, the question reads "using id's", and B, for all you know the timestamps are updated on edits. At least give some context to your answer.

Comment: We should not make big philosophy of this question and answer, this is novice StackOver user and simple question and one should expect that article_timestamp is used for defining the date and time of article (so the relation with last 5 and ordering upon it).

Comment: This would be a great solution indeed, but the timespan of news articles is like once in the 3 days, so I decided to get the latest added articles on ID. But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: With changing the (publication) date/time of your article you could easily change their order and you cannot do this easily by changing their ID, however I will note elaborate this simple thing any more, it's up to you what you will take a an column for sorting.

Comment: I dont need to change orders what so ever, so sorting them by ID will be enough for me.